# is there a fix for Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I always get this error when trying to download Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.0.
with the latest library

the error bellow

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
> Could not find
> com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.0.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing exactly the same issue .
After wasting couple of hours, I was able to resolve it and was able to connect to my parse server on AWS. But I am not happy with the documentation provided by Parse platform (https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/), which suggested to include this dependency.

It worked for me after I included the following dependencies in module build file:

```
implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
implementation "com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3"
```

And following in the project build file in repositories section:

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

As of now, I do not have the answer to why there is an issue with com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.0. Note that I was able to connect to parse server. I am providing below modifications too if you are facing connectivity issue. Manifest file change(had to add android:name) :

<application
android:name=".ParseApplication"

And initialize the Parse application:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId("myappID")
            // if defined
            .clientKey("xxxxxxxx")
            .server("http://13.232.198.174/parse/")
            .build()
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not find
>   com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.24.0.

Add this in your **`Project Level`** `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me, I had the repository "maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }" in the build script { repositories {...}} instead of allprojects { repositories { ...}} by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To use ParseSDK, you must add this (build.gradle->app);

```
     implementation "com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3"
```